# What is better for dict value assign a nonexistent key?

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose that I want to add a value to a dict, but I'm not sure if the key exists. What would be the better way (performance matter)? If there is some better way...

```
my_dict['key'] = my_dict.get('key', new_value) # I like this!
```

OR

```
if 'key' not in my_dict:
    my_dict['key'] = new_value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a built-in `dict` method for this:

```
my_dict.setdefault('key', new_value)
```

It returns the resulting value (i.e. the existing value if there was one, or the newly set one if there wasn't), which is useful in expressions like:

```
my_dict.setdefault('key', []).append('foo')
```

Comment: This is a better way! Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`dis(Disassembler for Python bytecode)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#:%7E:text=The%20dis%20module%20supports%20the,the%20compiler%20and%20the%20interpreter.) and check `run-time`. best approach base `run-time` and `dis` is **`if 'key' not in my_dict: my_dict['key'] = 'new_value'`**, because first and second approaches have `CALL_METHOD` but third approach doesn't have `CALL_METHOD`. *(Benchmark on [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/))*

```
my_dict = {i:i for i in range(10_000_000)}
%timeit my_dict['key'] = my_dict.get('key', 'new_value')
# 1000000 loops, best of 5: 123 ns per loop

%timeit my_dict.setdefault('key', 'new_value')
# 10000000 loops, best of 5: 90.7 ns per loop

%timeit if 'key' not in my_dict: my_dict['key'] = 'new_value'
# 10000000 loops, best of 5: 51 ns per loop
```

Check with `dis`

```
>>> import dis

>>> my_dict = {}
>>> dis.dis("my_dict.setdefault('key', 'new_value')")

  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (my_dict)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (setdefault)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 ('key')
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('new_value')
              8 CALL_METHOD              2
             10 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis.dis("my_dict['key'] = my_dict.get('key', 'new_value')")

  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (my_dict)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (get)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 ('key')
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('new_value')
              8 CALL_METHOD              2
             10 LOAD_NAME                0 (my_dict)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 ('key')
             14 STORE_SUBSCR
             16 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis.dis("if 'key' not in my_dict: my_dict['key'] = 'new_value'")

1             0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('key')
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (my_dict)
              4 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 ('new_value')
             10 LOAD_NAME                0 (my_dict)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 ('key')
             14 STORE_SUBSCR
        >>   16 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Really impressive.  *Seeing* is *believing*....   Do you know what's *performance* implications for each - if that's handy.  Thanks